# Add thumbnail image to Xcode Bot

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

I'd like to set the thumbnail image for an Xcode bot.

[image: screenshot of Xcode bot]

The project has a complete `.appiconset` folder for iPhone icons and these are shown on a device home screen when the application is installed. I assumed the bot would pull images from here but it appears not.

**What I've tried**

- Adding all other icon sets, including Mac, Watch and iPad.
- Adding the icon to the project as a separate .png file and referencing it within the info plist using the `CFBundleIcons` key.

Comment: Have you also added the new optional App Store Icon (1024x1024) to the asset catalog?

Comment: Yeah that's included, although without much luck

Comment: you cannot change the image from Xcode assets but you can do it from the JS file of the web page. its a static image its not rendering dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot update the image from the Xcode. The image which is getting displayed is the data which is stored in "webui-optimized.css". If you need it specifically you can change the image data there.

the file location will be at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcswebui/webui/stylesheets/webui-optimized.css"